# WPF & XAML Drag and Drop all children from 1 grid cell to another

Tags: wpf, xaml, drag

I have a grid, with each cell loaded from XAML (separate) files at runtime, where each cell contains child elements in the general form of:

```
<Border Name="R1C1Border">
  <Grid Name="R1C1Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="R1C1TextBlock1">blah blah blah</TextBlock> 
    <TextBlock Name="R1C1TextBlock2">blah blah blah</TextBlock>
    <Polygon.../>
    <Ellipse... ></Ellipse>
    <Path... etc.../>
    <Button></Button>
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

I'd like to implement drag and drop behavior to drag the border as well as all it's children to another cell to allow the user to customize the grid at runtime. I can copy the contents in code behind with FindName, GetChildren(), Child =, TypeOf etc.. but I'd really like to figure it out using drag and drop if possible. I've followed the MSDN basic drag and drop with Ellipse and ListBox but I think it's the nesting that throwing a wrench in the works when I try to apply it in this case. I've purchased several books for both XAML and WPF and Drag and Drop doesn't show up in the index.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same thing you are doing now only add another step on drag start:

Make VisaulBrush from your Control(the one you drag, with all its children).

Then open either a popup or a window, make the brush the background of it.
Add another step when moving Mouse:

Update popup/window location.